# Convolution of $e^{-at}u(t)$ and $e^{at}u(-t)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, convolution, step-function

I have following convolution:

$$e^{-at}u(t)*e^{at}u(-t);a>0$$

$u(t)$ is the unit step function.

I have tried the following:

$$\begin{align*}e^{-at}u(t)*e^{at}u(-t)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a\tau}u(\tau)\ e^{a(t-\tau)}u(-(t-\tau))\mathrm{d}\tau=e^{at} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2a\tau}u(\tau)\ u(\tau-t)\mathrm{d}\tau \\ &=e^{at}\int_{t}^{\infty}e^{-2a\tau}\mathrm{d}\tau=-\frac{e^{at}}{2a}[e^{-2a\tau}]_t^{\infty}=\frac{e^{-at}}{2a} \\ \end{align*}$$

But the given answer is $\displaystyle \frac{e^{-at}}{2a}u(t)+\frac{e^{at}}{2a}u(-t)$.

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong over here.

Comment: what is $u(t)$?

Comment: @pointguard0 Unit step function. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition,
\begin{equation}
 f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
 e^{-a \tau}u(\tau) e^{a(t-\tau)}u(\tau - t) \ d \tau
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
 f(t) = 
 e^{at}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
 e^{-2a \tau} u(\tau) u(\tau - t) \ d \tau
\end{equation}
Integral is non zero when $\tau > 0$ or $\tau - t > 0$ ($\tau >t$).

**Assuming $t>0$**
\begin{equation}
 f(t) = 
 e^{at}\int_{t}^{\infty} 
 e^{-2a \tau} \ d \tau
 =
 \frac{e^{at}}{2a}
 [  e^{-2at} ]
 =
 \frac{e^{-at}}{2a}
\end{equation}

**Assuming $t<0$**

If $t < 0$, then the above integral must start from $0$, 
\begin{equation}
 f(t) = 
 e^{at}\int_{0}^{\infty} 
 e^{-2a \tau} \ d \tau
 =
 \frac{e^{at}}{2a}
 [ 1 ]
 =
 \frac{e^{at}}{2a}
\end{equation}

**Combining both results**

We get
$$f(t) = \frac{e^{-at}}{2a}u(t) + \frac{e^{at}}{2a} u(-t)$$
i.e. the first term is non zero when $t >0$ and the second term is non zero when $t < 0$. Note that when one is zero, the other is zero.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if I was missing the $t<0$ part and indeed I was.

Comment: yes you were @paulplusx sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: No problem at all, thank you.